# How can I create an object type with a string name?

Tags: typescript

I have the following array

```
const roads = [
    "Alice's House-Bob's House",
    "Alice's House-Cabin",
    "Alice's House-Post Office",
    ...
];
```

**And I want to define a type Graph** that is an object and has name:value

In this case each string in the roads array is a direction where the string until '-' is the from and from there to the end the to.
So I want the type to be an object of a name string and a value of an array of strings.

Something like this:

```
{
  "Alice's House": [ "Bob's House", 'Cabin', 'Post Office' ],
  ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think something like `export type Graph = {[key: string]: string[]}` should be the right one for your data structure :) It says that every key in the object will be a string and every value in the object will be a string array.

Comment: @Doc Thanks! Easy question I guess, I'm just getting started with TS and sometimes I get lost with the most basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 options to do this:

1. Use index type

```
type Address {
 [key: string]: string[]
}
```

2. Use `Record` [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

```
type Address = Record<string, string[]>
```